# SQL Server 2012 Insert XML into table issue

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a generic update procedure.  The point of this procedure is that we want to be able to track everything that happens in a table.  If a recordis updated, we need to be able to know who changed that record, what it was originally, what it is after the change and when the change occurred.  We only do this on our most important tables where accountability is a must.

Right now, we do this through a combination of web server programming and SQL Server commands.

I need to take what we currently have, and make a SQL only version.

So, here are the requirements of what I need:

The original sp is called UpdateWithHistory.  Right now, it takes 4 parameters all varchar (or it can be nvarchar, doesn't matter).  They are the table name, the primary key field, primary key value and a comma delimited list of fields and values in the format field='value',field1='value1'...etc.

In the background, we have a mapping table that we use to map the string table names to actual tables.

In the stored procedure, I have tried various combinations of OPENROWSET, exec(), select into, xml, and other methods.  None seem to work.

So basically, I have to be able to dynamically generate a simple select statement (no joins or other complicated select stuff) from the 4 supplied parameters, then store the results of that query in a table.  Since it is dynamic, I don't know the number of fields being queried, or what data types they will be.

I tried select into since that will automatically create a table with the appropriate fields and data types, but it doesn't work in conjunction with the exec command.  I have also tried

```
exec sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@output xml output', @resultXML output
```

Where @resultXML is XML datatype and @SQL is the sql command.  @resultXML always ends up as null, no matter what I do.  I also tried the xml route because I know that "FOR XML Path" always returns one column, but I can't use that in an insert into statement....

That statement output will be used to determine the original values before the update.

I figure once I get past this hurdle the rest will be a piece of cake.  Anyone got any ideas?

So here is code for something that I finally got to work, although I don't want to use global tables, so I would gladly accept a different answer...

```
DECLARE @curRecordString varchar(max) = 'SELECT * into ##TEMP_TABLE FROM SOMEDB.dbo.' + @tbl + ' WHERE ' + @prikey + ' = ''' + @prival + ''' '
exec(@curRecordString)
```

Basically, as stated before, I need to dynamically build a sql query, then store the result of running the query so that I can access it later.  I would prefer to store it as XML datatype, since I will later be using XQuery to parse and compare nodes.  In the code above, I am using a global temp table (not ideal, I know) to store the result of the query so that the rest of my procedure can access the data.

Like I said, I don't like this approach but hopefully someone else can come up with something better that will allow me to dynamically build a SQL query, run it, store the results so that I can access the results later in the stored procedure.

Comment: Why don't you simply use [Microsoft SQL Server Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: Number 1, don't know what that is.  Number 2, the system that my company uses is over 10 years old and was originally designed when classic asp and VBScript were new.  So anything that we do needs to conform to this old system.

Comment: I followed your link, it looks like it would work in most cases, but not mine, since my boss wants to keep all the tracking history in this table that he created years ago....

Comment: How about presenting the solution to your boss and explaining to him the cost/benefits of using his old scheme vs. using this one? What value is there in using some old table? Perhaps it would help if you told us what version of SQL Server (2000, 2005, 2008, 2012?)

Comment: Originally, it was probably SQL Server 2000.  Now we are on 2012, so we CAN use newer techniques.  And he is very inflexible with making changes that don't conform to the way things are currently done.  It took me many months just to get him to allow AJAX in our current system, so I don't think it is a fight that I can win.  Also, our current system that we use is all home grown, with many hooks into this history table, so from his standpoint the cost vs benefit of rewriting many thousands of lines of code that tie into updating and maintaining the old history table aren't that beneficial.

Comment: You should probably start adding a lot of code to illustrate what you're trying to do, what you did in the past, and any errors that you received.  Include samples and schemas.

Comment: Yes... there really isn't enough information to help you. How about starting with showing the contents of the `@SQL` variable?

Comment: I added some code that I got to work, but am not happy with.  I don't want to use global variables because I don't want to run the risk of something outside the currently running SP inadvertantly putting bad data in the global table. The sql variable is any simple select statement.  Nothing really special about it, other than the fact that one query can have only 2 columns, while the next can have 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most definitely a hack, but...

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @s = 'SELECT (SELECT 1 as splat FOR XML PATH) a'

CREATE TABLE #save (x XML)

INSERT INTO #save
        ( x )
EXEC (@s)


SELECT  * FROM #save s

DROP TABLE #save
```

Comment: That doesn't work if you specify a table in the inner Select query.  You get the error "Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it with a table, and it worked for me.  Can you post a version of what you tried?  I did SET @s= 'SELECT (SELECT * FROM table FOR XML PATH) a'

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong while I was explaining what I did to you.  I changed the SELECT 1 to SELECT *, then I included the table between splat and FOR.  I forgot to remove 'as splat'.  When I removed that, it worked fine.  Also, I swear I tried something very similar to what you put above, and I couldn't get it to work, but for some reason it works now, so I will just go ahead and call it good.  Thanks.